# xpra is stopped when logging in from sddm

Tags: ssh, login, xpra

I use xpra on a computer to run programs in its virtual X11 server. I start it via ssh, then I can attach and detach without any problems and everything keeps running.

When I now login via sddm as the same user, the xpra session is killed and I do not know why.

I suspect that maybe systemd is killing old sessions when logigng into a new one or something similar.

Comment: Are you using Debian or Ubuntu by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I tested it both on Debian and Ubuntu and had the same problem. I did not test it on other distributions.

Comment: The problem is specific to those two distributions, they modify something in the X11 stack which causes those problems.
You may want to enable --start-via-proxy=yes and see if that helps. Sorry.

Comment: The best thing to do is to avoid Debian based distributions, no other distribution has these self inflicted problems.
This has been going on for years and still is not fixed. Shambles.